# Javascript calculate IPv6 range from CIDR prefix

Tags: javascript, ip-address, ipv6, cidr

Using Javascript (without JQuery) I'm looking to get the minimum and maximum IPs in a IPv6 CIDR prefix.

For example, `2001:280::/32` would output `2001:280:0:0:0:0:0:0` and `2001:280:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check out https://github.com/franksrevenge/IPSubnetCalculator?

Comment: @MatthewVita that seems to only work with IPv4 addresses sadly.

Comment: I see that now :*(. I believe I found a solution for you (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Node and NPM installed:

```
$ touch index.js
$ npm init
$ npm i --save ip-address
$ vim index.js

var v6 = require('ip-address').v6;

var addr = new v6.Address('2001:280::/32');

console.log(addr.parsedAddress.join(':'));
console.log(addr.endAddress().address);

$ <esc>:wq
$ node index.js
2001:280:0:0:0:0:0:0
2001:0280:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

There doesn't seem to be a browser facing package so I'd suggest using Browserify (http://browserify.org/) to get this to work *or* fork the project and stuff everything into one file so you can run it in your browser (leaving out the node-specific code, of course).

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually compute the upper limit. IPv6 allows putting "all" the 2^48 MAC addresses on one /64, but even if you could do that, you can't do it twice, because once you've connected all of them to one there are no left for other networks. Therefore, the theoretical upper limit for a /64 is roughly 2^48 devices, for a /48 also 2^48, and for a /32 it is the same 2^48. What this means in practice is that IPv6 is free of certain kinds of limitations, and counting those limitated resources is meaningless.

Comment: @arnt, while I agree that 18 quintillion addresses per /64 is a ridiculous number, your reasoning is incorrect. IPv6 allows any number of IPv6 addresses per interface (MAC address) so, in theory, you could use all the available addresses on a /64, although you couldn't live long enough to get them all assigned. IPv6 also converts the 48-bit MAC into a 64-bit number when using SLAAC, and IEEE has revamped the 48-bit MAC with the new 64-bit EUI. Certainly, today, there is no way to actually use every address in a /64, but IPv6 is designed to have room for the future.

Comment: Oh, right. For some reason I thought the question was about devices, not addresses. Still, the answer remains "pointless, because enough", just with different reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ip6` npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip6

`ip6` helps to normalize, abbreviate, divide subnets, generate random subnets/hosts and calculate range of size of an IPv6 subnet.

```
let ip6 = require('ip6');
console.log(ip6.range('2001:280:0:0:0:0:0:0', 32));
{ start: '2001:0280:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000',
  end: '2001:0280:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff',
  size: 7.922816251426434e+28 }
```

Or in command line:

```
ip6 -R 2001:280:0:0:0:0:0:0 32
{"start":"2001:0280:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000","end":"2001:0280:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff","size":7.922816251426434e+28}
```