# Retrieve IPv6 address range from CIDR in javascript

Tags: javascript, range, ipv6, cidr

Let's say that we have a given IPv6 CIDR (e.g 2001:db8::/32)
Could you tell me how we can find out the first and last address from this CIDR by using javascript?

I have checked the solution provided here: 
[Javascript calculate IPv6 range from CIDR prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296203/javascript-calculate-ipv6-range-from-cidr-prefix)

but in my case i cannot use ip6 package due to restrictions.
I would like if possible to implement this only by using the built-in/default javascript libraries.

Comment: The package is also written is JS, you can take a look at the source: https://github.com/elgs/ip6/blob/master/ip6.js - so yes this is possible in JS :-)

Comment: @TobiasK Maybe he cannot, because he works in a company where they restrict the use of third party code.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this JS file but i am not totally sure if this will be compatible on my environment. In any case, i would like to know of any other possible solutions (if any)